# Why can I reference RecordCount on a query embedded in an object but I can't loop over it?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfoutput

I have a model, `surveyTemplate`, that has all but one of it's properties populated by a query.

I am storing an additional query in the last property of the model which is called, `surveyTemplateQuestions`.

If I do the following:

```
writeDump(var="#surveyTemplateObj#"); abort;
```

I get the model correctly populated with the last property containing the query data.

I can also do this:

```
writeDump(var="#surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions()#"); abort;
```

And now I get just the query stored in the last property of the model.

So, why can I not do this:

```
<cfoutput query="prc.surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions()">
```

When doing the above I get the following error:

> The value of the attribute query, which is currently prc.surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions(), is invalid.

But then I can do this instead:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#prc.surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions().RecordCount#" index="i">
```

How can it be that when I do a `cfdump` of the object's last property it shows as a query, I can do a `RecordCount` on the query object, but I cannot loop over the query object via `cfoutput`?

Comment: Just to clarify, if you look at [the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfoutput.html), it says it expects the *name* of query, ie string, not a query *object* or something like a function that returns a query object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
prc.surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions()
```

is a function result.  If you want to loop through it, assign it to a variable first:

```
myVariable = prc.surveyTemplateObj.getSurveyTemplateQuestions();

<cfoutput query = "myVariable">
etc
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for the reply.  I believe I did try this but I am going to double check right now.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected.  I must have goofed earlier, you are, of course, correct.  Thanks!